# Mongoose upload of posted object failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm new to nodeJS, simple post data upload to Mongo failing. My connection is working. If I put in the code:

```
var itemOne = steTodo({task: 'something', date: 'something', status: 
'something' }).save(function(err)
   {
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log('Item saved');
   });
```

This works and inserts a record.

However, if I try to upload posted data in this way:

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res)
    {
        res.render('index', {data: req.body});
        console.log(req.body);
       //get data from the view and add it to mongodb

       var newSteTodo = steTodo(req.body).save(function(err, data)
       {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Item Saved" + req.body)
            //res.json(data);
       });
    });
```

It fails and tells me it failed to render the object as a string. It doesn't help when I add in JSON.stringify() the posted object. Console.log above outputs the posted object as e.g. below:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  task: 'hello',
  date: 'Thu Jul 25 2019 14:55:42 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)',
  status: 'New' }
```

As I'm a newbie to Node I'm sure I'm doing something silly, any help appreciated.

Comment: Data you are receiving is not in JSON format. if you are using bodyParser package u can simply do `bodyParser.json()` to convert incming data to JSON

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that: var jsonParsed = bodyParser.json(req.body); but I got an error saying 'body already parsed'. I'm even more confused now :/

Comment: What is urlencodedParser in your route?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to Shivam Sood for helping me to debug this, it was very helpful. Turns out it was just me being silly. It actually was creating the DB record. But after the upload it was crashing the node app, this was to do with the format of the console.log. The solution is below using JSON.stringify

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res)
    {
        res.render('index', {data: req.body});
        console.log(req.body);
       //get data from the view and add it to mongodb

       var newSteTodo = steTodo(req.body).save(function(err, data)
       {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Item Saved" + JSON.stringify(req.body))
            //res.json(data);
       });
    });
```

Comment: Glad it worked out, if you don’t mind please correct my name thanks :)